# Using Hermit Reasoner to check if an Ontology is Consistant

Tags: reasoning, hermit

does anyone know how to use Hermit reasoner to check if the Ontology is inconsistent/consistent ?
i want to use it from command line and would be better if I can save the result in result.txt like Konclude.

Answer (score 0):

```
➜ java -jar HermiT.jar -k ~/my.owl
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing is satisfiable.
```

if you wanna save the result as result.txt

in linux and macOS

```
➜ java -jar HermiT.jar -k ~/my.owl > result.txt 

➜ cat result.txt   
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing is satisfiable
```

or use `-o` to write output to file

```
java -jar HermiT.jar -k ~/my.owl -o result.txt
```